# get data from multiple models in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models Policy, CustomerAccount, CustomerAccountYourDetails

**Policy**

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    customer_account = models.ForeignKey(CustomerAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**CustomerAccount**

```
class CustomerAccount(models.Model):
    username = models.EmailField("Email Address")    
    date_first_registered = models.DateTimeField()
```

**CustomerAccountYourDetails**

```
class CustomerAccountYourDetails(models.Model):
    customer_account = models.ForeignKey(CustomerAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    first_name = models.CharField("First name", max_length = 30)
    dob = models.DateField("Date of Birth")
```

**In views.py function**

```
policies = Policy.objects.all()
return render(request, 'html file name', 'policies':policies)
```

**in html template**

following works

```
{% for policy in policies %}
{{policy.date}}  //gives the date as expected
{{policy.customer_account.username}} //gives the username as expected
{{need to get first name of customer here}}
{{need to get dob of customer here}}
{% endfor %}
```

how can i get the first_name and dob from CustomerAccountYourDetails model which is my third model

Comment: Is this not working? - `{% for customer in policy.customer_account.customeraccountyourdetails_set.all %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
{% for policy in policies %}
{{policy.date}} 
{% for customer in policy.customeraccount_set.all %}
{{customer.name}}
{% for customer_detail in customer.customerdetails_set.all %}
{{customer_detail.dob }}
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```